# Custom colorbar in healpy mollview

Tags: python, matplotlib, healpy

I am trying to replace the colorbar given by "hp.mollview" with a custom one. In particular I am interested in:

- Rotating the colorbar by 90 degrees (i.e. replacing the horizontal by a vertical one)
- Using two labels (left and right of the colorbar)
- Setting custom ticks
- Indicating that the range is set (via the "max" parameter) by setting "cmap.set_over".

Minimal amount of code:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
m = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(32))
hp.mollview(m)
```

Any help?

Comment: you should disable the colorbar in `mollview` and then add a custom one with `Figure.colorbar`

Comment: Can you a minimal amount of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll expand my comment here:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(32))
hp.mollview(m, cbar=None)

fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
image = ax.get_images()[0]
cmap = fig.colorbar(image, ax=ax)
```

Then you can customize the `colorbar` with the function arguments.